# PrimeNG better highlighting of a selected item in a tree

Tags: css, angular

Out of the box the  control highlights a selected item with a light blue border. I can't see where this is coming from, and I'd like to make the styling a bit more emphatic.
I compared a selected and unselected node in the dom, and they look basically the same:

Unselected node:

```
<div role="treeitem"
     class="p-treenode-content p-treenode-selectable"
     draggable="false"
     ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"
     tabindex="0"
     aria-posinset="4"
     aria-selected="false"
     aria-label="Label1">...
</div>
```

Selected node:

```
<div role="treeitem"
     class="p-treenode-content p-treenode-selectable"
     draggable="false"
     ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"
     tabindex="0"
     aria-posinset="5"
     aria-selected="false"
     aria-label="Label2">...
</div>
```

I'd expect the selected node to have a class added or some other attribute I can key off for CSS, but these look identical. I can definitely put something in to set the class, but that seems ugly and something p-tree should support out of the box. But I can't see anything in the generated HTML or the API description to tell me how to do it. Something is going on because it does have that blue border, but I can't see where it is coming from. Maybe `ng-reflect-ng-class` but not sure how I'd use that.

Ultimately I want a CSS selector that allows me to set the selected item to, for example, have a gray background.